# ios swift - Save device token as data format printing different values

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults, devicetoken

I tried save devicetoken into userDefaults for later use.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
print(deviceToken) // value print as 32 bytes

 let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: deviceToken)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData , forKey: "deviceToken")


 let decoded  = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "deviceToken")
print(decoded) // value print as 172 bytes
}
```

i don't know whether the printing value is correct or not.
how to verify it? or if my storing mechanism is wrong. how can i save data for later usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encoding `Data` to `Data` is redundant, just save the token directly

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(deviceToken, forKey: "deviceToken")
```

and you can display the bytes with

```
print(deviceToken as NSData)
```

> for later use

What use? The server which sends the notification needs to maintain the token but not the client.

Comment: i need to pass devicetoken to a SDK in a different view controller

Comment: Got it, but `UserDefaults` is the wrong place to share data between view controllers. Pass the data directly in a segue or during instantiation.

Comment: is it secure to store device token in user default ?

Comment: @Yodagama On iOS yes, but why? Please read the last sentence in my answer.

Comment: @vadian if we send request with the device token every time we get from the system , the server will get more requests. so ; shouldn’t  we need to compare  the old one (from the cache) with the new one to check wether the device token changed ?

Comment: @Yodagama The amount of extra requests is negligible. And it's a good practice to provide other information to the server like device model, notification settings, maybe OS version to be more flexible.

Comment: @vadian It is not negligible in a app that has a huge user base.  device model, notification settings, maybe OS .. does not solve a actual problem. but adds a flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need of use `NSKeyedArchiver`, this is the reason that you get a wrong value. In order to save data in UserDefaults (which is not safe at all):

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(deviceToken, forKey: "kDeviceToken")
```

In order to retrieve it you should use :

```
let deviceToken = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "kDeviceToken")
```

If you want to secure the data that you are saving I recommend you to use Keychain, reference here: https://fluffy.es/persist-data/

Comment: No, don't use `value(forKey` unless you know what KVC is and you really need KVC (here you don't). `data(forKey` is the correct API.

Comment: @vadian thank you for mentioning, I update my answer.